# How to add a button into the window, like firefox has?

Tags: vb.net

How to add a button into the window, like the one Firefox has? (VB.NET if possible):

[screenshot http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/d021/92rxd53chcvcj0k6g.jpg](http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/d021/92rxd53chcvcj0k6g.jpg)

Comment: You want a button in your form like the one in the link?

Comment: As a start yes. Just would like to know how to do that.